# 2009 Chrysler T&C Van - power door repair

Tags: power, chrysler, door, van

Our driver side back power door will not work... it seems that something had gotten caught in it and now it will not move the door on its' own.  It makes the sound, but doesn't move it.  I am assuming the chain/ chord broke.  Is this easy to fix on ones own?